# Meaning of "きっちり" here?

Tags: translation

This dialogue when a shop is offering bonus items.

> 料金分はきっちり
>
> 仕事させて貰いますから

By context of the dialogues, I feel that the first line should mean something like "The fee stays the same." But can きっちりbe used in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 料金分{りょうきんぶん}はきっちり
>
> 仕事{しごと}させて貰{もら}いますから

In this context, 「きっちり」 means "properly", "exactly", etc.

「料金分はきっちり」 literally means "exactly the fee's worth".

My own TL:

> Literal: "I shall work for exactly the fee's worth."
>
> Free: "I'm going to work exactly as much as you are paying for."